# Unable to add_index column on Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter

Hey Fellow Coders,

I am in need of your HELP.

Rails version:  4.2.4
Ruby version:  ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]

I am trying to make a twitter clone following this tutorial on youtube. 
---**link:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4S4Wyndbnn0.

Everything worked fine for me up to **7:35** mark on the video

After I run the command "rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string:uniq". All the of the appropriate file appears on the file tree in Sublime text but when i go to the schema.rb

```
--I can't seem to find the "the add_index users, ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true doesn't show. " in the schema.rb directory
```

Below are the files:

app/db/migrate/add_username_to_users

```
class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string
    add_index :users, :username, unique: true
  end
end
```

app/db/schema

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160210202649) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

this is what i get when i run  rake db:migrate

```
== 20160210230711 AddUsernameToUsers: migrating ===============================
-- add_column(:users, :username, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: username: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "username" varchar/Users/krischery/TwitterClone/db/migrate/20160210230711_add_username_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: username: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "username" varchar
/Users/krischery/TwitterClone/db/migrate/20160210230711_add_username_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: username
/Users/krischery/TwitterClone/db/migrate/20160210230711_add_username_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Kriss-MBP:TwitterClone krischery$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20160210230711 AddUsernameToUsers: migrating ===============================
-- add_column(:users, :username, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: username: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "username" varchar/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `block in execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:453:in `add_column'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:631:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:288:in `measure'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:631:in `say_with_time'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:651:in `method_missing'
/Users/krischery/TwitterClone/db/migrate/20160210230711_add_username_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:605:in `exec_migration'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:288:in `measure'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `block in migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: username: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "username" varchar
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `block in execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:453:in `add_column'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:631:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:288:in `measure'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:631:in `say_with_time'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:651:in `method_missing'
/Users/krischery/TwitterClone/db/migrate/20160210230711_add_username_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:605:in `exec_migration'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:288:in `measure'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `block in migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: username
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `block in execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:453:in `add_column'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:631:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:288:in `measure'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:631:in `say_with_time'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:651:in `method_missing'
/Users/krischery/TwitterClone/db/migrate/20160210230711_add_username_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:605:in `exec_migration'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:288:in `measure'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `block in migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/krischery/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
Kriss-MBP:TwitterClone krischery$
```